# Не срабатывает isql запрос в ajax

Tags: ajax

Не срабатывает sql запрос в ajax .5 выводит, а сам запрос нет, я что-то делаю не так?

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "searchzk.php",
        data: {'count':s_user},
        success: function(data){
           $("#results").html(data);    
       }
   })
```

В самом файле searchzk.php:

```
require_once ("../bd.php");
if(!empty($_POST["count"])){ 
//Принимаем данные
$count = $_POST["count"];
$db_referal = mysql_query("SELECT `zhk-name`, `zhk-id` from zhk ");
$zkh= mysql_fetch_array($db_referal);
echo 5;
echo $zkh["zhk-name"];
```

Comment: так может это поле пустое в первой записи результата

Comment: Нет там все поля записаны, но поменял на id результат тот же ((((((

Comment: - a c `$zkh[0]`?

Comment: Рабочий пример вот какой, НО if(!empty($_POST["count"])){ //Принимаем данные
$count = $_POST["count"];


$db_referal = $mysqli -> query("SELECT  `zhk-id` from zhk WHERE `zhk-name`='$count' ")
    or die('Ошибка №'.__LINE__.'<br>Обратитесь к администратору сайта пожалуйста, сообщив номер ошибки.');

    while ($row = $db_referal -> fetch_array()) {
        echo "\n<li>".$row["zhk-id"]."</li>"; //$row["name"] - имя ЖК в таблице
    }

echo 5; если я оптимизирую строчку   while ($row = $db_referal -> fetch_array()) {
        echo $row["zhk-id"]; //
    } }
echo 5; не показывает 5ку

Comment: Видимо опять проблемы с ковычками, сделал для его echo  "\n5"; стало и 5ку показывать

Comment: Теперь не выводится  ПОЧЕМУ SOS!!!      $a = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM object');
$b = mysql_fetch_array( $a );
echo $b[0]; // выведет число строк*/